# Grouping by date in descending order, but outputting records within date in ascending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by

With the following query I'm getting the records grouped by date in descending order, i.e. starting today and going back chronologically:

```
impressions = Impression.order(created_at: :desc).group_by {|impression| impression.created_at.to_date}
```

But when looping the nested `Hash` and outputting each day's records, I would like to have those in ascending order - i.e. starting with the first records created that particular day.

How could I acoomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, but be aware, that for large collections, performance could be bad:

```
impressions = Impression.order(created_at: :desc).group_by {|impression| impression.created_at.to_date}
puts impressions.sort
# [[Sun, 05 Jan 2014, [#<Impressions id: 1..>,#<Impressions id: 2..>]], [Fr, 03 Jan 2014, [#<Impressions id: 3..>,#<Impressions id: 4..>]]]
```

But i don't understand, why you are sorting `desc` in your DB and then you want a `asc` order? Why don't you just use `asc` in your statement?

```
impressions = Impression.order(created_at: :asc).group_by {|impression| impression.created_at.to_date}
```

Comment: Alright, `impression.sort` made it! That simple, thank you. (I want to display the records grouped by date chronologically backwards, but the records within each "day-group" should be displayed by time.)